# How can I can Parse the xml into a list variable

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse the xml into a list variable from its root tag. I have given below the xml file format. I want to get the entire content of the xml into a list variable excluding the first line

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Root>
  <Database>
    Data Source
  </Database>
  <FromEmailDetails>
    <UserName>
      testuser
    </UserName>
    <Password>
      myPassword
    </Password>
    <FromAddress>
      test@gmail.com
    </FromAddress>
    <Server>
      myserver
    </Server>
    <port>
      80
    </port>
  </FromEmailDetails>
  <FileFormat>
    XLSX
  </FileFormat>
  <ExportFolder>
    C:\NOTNEED\
  </ExportFolder>
  <Customer>
    <SQL ID="GYSQL">
      Select * from customer where code ='GYSQL'
    </SQL>
    <MailBody>
      Please find attached Report
    </MailBody>
    <Address>customer1@mail.com</Address>
    <Address>customer2@mail.com</Address>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <SQL ID="TSSQL">
      Select * from customer where code ='TSSQL'
    </SQL>
    <MailBody>
      Please find attached Report
    </MailBody>
    <Address>customer3@mail.com</Address>
    <Address>customer4@mail.com</Address>
    <Address>customer5@mail.com</Address>
  </Customer>
</Root>
```

I am trying to parse the xml into a list

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(textXML);
var contents = xml  .ToList();  // Please help here how can I store the xml content as list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
foreach (var entry in doc.Descendants()) 
{
    contents.Add(entry);
}
```

Comment: How can I declare contents variable

Comment: List<string> contents = new List<string>(); @systemthreep

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication176
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            DataBase db = new DataBase(root);
  
        }
    }
    public class DataBase
    {
        public string database { get; set; }
        public Email email { get; set; }
        public string fileFormat { get; set; }
        public string exportFolder { get; set; }
        public List<Customer> customers { get; set; }
        public DataBase(XElement root)
        {
            database = ((string)root.Element("Database")).Trim();
            fileFormat = ((string)root.Element("FileFormat")).Trim();
            exportFolder = ((string)root.Element("ExportFolder")).Trim();
            email = new Email(root.Element("FromEmailDetails"));
            customers = root.Elements("Customer").Select(x => new Customer(x)).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class Email
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string fromAddress { get; set; }
        public string server { get; set; }
        public int port { get; set; }

        public Email(XElement email)
        {
            username = ((string)email.Element("UserName")).Trim();
            password = ((string)email.Element("Password")).Trim();
            fromAddress = ((string)email.Element("FromAddress")).Trim();
            server = ((string)email.Element("Server")).Trim();
            port = (int)email.Element("port");
        }
    }
    public class Customer
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string sql { get; set; }
        public string mailBody { get; set; }
        public List<string> addresses { get; set; }

        public Customer(XElement customer)
        {
            id = ((string)customer.Element("SQL").Attribute("ID")).Trim();
            sql = ((string)customer.Element("SQL")).Trim();
            mailBody = ((string)customer.Element("SQL")).Trim();
            addresses = customer.Elements("Address").Select(x => ((string)x).Trim()).ToList();
        }
    }
  
}
```